# Grid elements overlapping in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid, bulma

I have a table with a row that needs to show data with nested rows. To make sure the data for "Attendee Name, Title" and "Attendee Company, Org., or other" are vertically spacing the content correctly and showing the data on the correct row, I am attempting to use grid. This works well in Chrome but in IE, the two grid columns are overlapping on a smaller display.

How can I correct this for IE11?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "Left Right";
  column-gap: 1.5em;
}

.Left {
  grid-area: Left;
}

.Right {
  grid-area: Right;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  .grid-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .Left {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    padding-right: .75em;
  }

  .Right {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    padding-left: .75em;
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table is-fullwidth">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Transaction Date</th>
          <th>Merchant Name</th>
          <th>Transaction Amount</th>
          <th>Expense Type</th>
          <th>Expense Category</th>
          <th>Business Purpose</th>
          <th>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">Attendee Name, Title</div>
              <div class="Right">Attendee Company, Org., or other</div>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12/15/2019</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>14.97</td>
          <td>Business Travel</td>
          <td>Single Day Mean/Incidental</td>
          <td>A really long paragraph could be here to show Business Purpose.</td>
          <td>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                John Doe, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                Some Company
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                Jane Smith, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                Some Company
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12/18/2019</td>
          <td>Nike</td>
          <td>9.96</td>
          <td>Business Travel</td>
          <td>Airline Ticket</td>
          <td>A really long paragraph could be here to show Business Purpose.</td>
          <td>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">
                Jane Doe, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="Right">
                Another Company
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">
                John Smith, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="Right">
                Another Company
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the issue where I found that it is overlapping the elements in IE 11 browser.

[image]

I check the code and found that if you remove the below code from **@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {.grid-container** then the issue can be solved in IE 11 browser.

```
-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Modified code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "Left Right";
  column-gap: 1.5em;
}

.Left {
  grid-area: Left;
}

.Right {
  grid-area: Right;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  .grid-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    /*-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .Left {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    padding-right: .75em;
  }

  .Right {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    padding-left: .75em;
  }

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table is-fullwidth">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Transaction Date</th>
          <th>Merchant Name</th>
          <th>Transaction Amount</th>
          <th>Expense Type</th>
          <th>Expense Category</th>
          <th>Business Purpose</th>
          <th>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">Attendee Name, Title</div>
              <div class="Right">Attendee Company, Org., or other</div>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12/15/2019</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>14.97</td>
          <td>Business Travel</td>
          <td>Single Day Mean/Incidental</td>
          <td>A really long paragraph could be here to show Business Purpose.</td>
          <td>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                John Doe, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                Some Company
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                Jane Smith, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                Some Company
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12/18/2019</td>
          <td>Nike</td>
          <td>9.96</td>
          <td>Business Travel</td>
          <td>Airline Ticket</td>
          <td>A really long paragraph could be here to show Business Purpose.</td>
          <td>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">
                Jane Doe, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="Right">
                Another Company
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="Left">
                John Smith, Analyst
              </div>
              <div class="Right">
                Another Company
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]